# Centering a Date in cell in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my table I have three lines of code which enter all the the data in my JTable apart from the last column. However I am not sure to as why.

```
   `DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );
    myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, centerRenderer);`
```

[image: Shows centered columns]

I think it is because I use a separate "DefaultTableCellRenderer" to sort my dates but I am not sure.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
///////////
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
///////////
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JtableIe
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Compare Tables");

    JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel();

    JScrollPane myScrollTable;
    JTable myTable;
    JTextField srchFld1;
    JTextField srchFld2;
    TableRowSorter sorter;
    JLabel srchLbl1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel srchLbl2 = new JLabel();
    DefaultTableModel model;

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 1296, 756);

        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createFirstPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createFirstPanel()
    {
        firstPanel.setLayout(null);

        srchLbl1.setLocation(0,0);
        srchLbl1.setSize(150,26);
        srchLbl1.setText("Name Search:");
        firstPanel.add(srchLbl1);

        srchLbl2.setLocation(660,0);
        srchLbl2.setSize(150,26);
        srchLbl2.setText("ID Search:");
        firstPanel.add(srchLbl2);

        String[] aHeaders = {"Name","ID","Number 1","Number 2","Time","Date"};
        Object[][] aData = new Object[15][6];

        ///////Data////////
        aData[0][0] = "John";
        aData[0][1] = "JS96";
        aData[0][2] = "1";
        aData[0][3] = "186";
        aData[0][4] = "1h 23m";
        aData[0][5] = getJavaDate("12-11-2015");

        aData[1][0] = "David";
        aData[1][1] = "DB36";
        aData[1][2] = "2";
        aData[1][3] = "111852";
        aData[1][4] = "2h 55m";
        aData[1][5] = getJavaDate("12-11-2020");

        aData[2][0] = "Daniel";
        aData[2][1] = "DK73";
        aData[2][2] = "3";
        aData[2][3] = "2921";
        aData[2][4] = "1h 55m";
        aData[2][5] = getJavaDate("12-11-2014");

        aData[3][0] = "Janis";
        aData[3][1] = "JW84";
        aData[3][2] = "4";
        aData[3][3] = "6512";
        aData[3][4] = "12h 26m";
        aData[3][5] = getJavaDate("13-11-2015");

        aData[4][0] = "Adam";
        aData[4][1] = "AF98";
        aData[4][2] = "5";
        aData[4][3] = "7524";
        aData[4][4] = "5h 47m";
        aData[4][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[5][0] = "Matthew";
        aData[5][1] = "MB55";
        aData[5][2] = "6";
        aData[5][3] = "4989";
        aData[5][4] = "80h 30m";
        aData[5][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[6][0] = "Lewis";
        aData[6][1] = "LS23";
        aData[6][2] = "7";
        aData[6][3] = "56321";
        aData[6][4] = "880h 20m";
        aData[6][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[7][0] = "Mark";
        aData[7][1] = "ML49";
        aData[7][2] = "8";
        aData[7][3] = "97456";
        aData[7][4] = "8h 42m";
        aData[7][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[8][0] = "Josh";
        aData[8][1] = "JT67";
        aData[8][2] = "9";
        aData[8][3] = "82135";
        aData[8][4] = "56h 13m";
        aData[8][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[9][0] = "Oliver";
        aData[9][1] = "OC98";
        aData[9][2] = "10";
        aData[9][3] = "152";
        aData[9][4] = "9h 9m";
        aData[9][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[10][0] = "Tom";
        aData[10][1] = "TS97";
        aData[10][2] = "11";
        aData[10][3] = "100";
        aData[10][4] = "0h 0m";
        aData[10][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[11][0] = "Emma";
        aData[11][1] = "EBS74";
        aData[11][2] = "12";
        aData[11][3] = "200";
        aData[11][4] = "0h 30m";
        aData[11][5] = getJavaDate("11-11-2015");

        aData[12][0] = "Lucy";
        aData[12][1] = "LK02";
        aData[12][2] = "13";
        aData[12][3] = "256";
        aData[12][4] = "7h 00m";
        aData[12][5] = getJavaDate("10001-11-2015");

        aData[13][0] = "Patrick";
        aData[13][1] = "PM38";
        aData[13][2] = "14";
        aData[13][3] = "258";
        aData[13][4] = "2h 00m";
        aData[13][5] = getJavaDate("31-02-2016");

        aData[14][0] = "Nicola";
        aData[14][1] = "NB70";
        aData[14][2] = "15";
        aData[14][3] = "987";
        aData[14][4] = "100h 56m";
        aData[14][5] = getJavaDate("31-02-2015");
        //////////////
        model = new DefaultTableModel(aData, aHeaders)
        {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) 
            {
                switch (column)
                {
                    case 5: return Date.class;
                    default: return Object.class;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) 
            {
               //all cells false
               return false;
            }
        };

        myTable = new JTable(model);

        myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        sorter = new TableRowSorter(myTable.getModel());
        List sortKeys = new ArrayList();
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(5, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        sorter.setComparator(2, new AlphanumComparator());
        sorter.setComparator(3, new AlphanumComparator());
        sorter.setComparator(4, new AlphanumComparator());
        setRenderers();
        myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.CENTER );
        myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, centerRenderer);

        DefaultRowSorter sorter = (DefaultRowSorter) myTable.getRowSorter();

        myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(50);
        myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(100);
        myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(75);



        myScrollTable = new JScrollPane(myTable); 
        myScrollTable.setSize(1296,756); 
        myScrollTable.setLocation(0,25); 
        System.out.println("Creating compare table");

        srchFld1 = new JTextField(10);
        srchFld1.setSize(550,26); 
        srchFld1.setLocation(100,0);
        srchFld1.setToolTipText("Enter Name");
        firstPanel.add(srchFld1);

        srchFld2 = new JTextField(10);
        srchFld2.setSize(550,26); 
        srchFld2.setLocation(740,0);
        srchFld2.setToolTipText("Enter ID");
        firstPanel.add(srchFld2);

        //////////////////////
        Document doc = srchFld1.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        doc.addDocumentListener(listener);

        ///////////////
        Document docb = srchFld2.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listenerb = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        docb.addDocumentListener(listenerb);
        ///////////////

        firstPanel.add(myScrollTable);
    }

    private static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private void setRenderers() 
    {
        myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, new DateRenderer());
    }

    private Date getJavaDate(String s) 
    {
        try 
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            Date d = sdf.parse(s);
            return d;
        } 

        catch (ParseException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(TableBasic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void newFilter()
    {
        RowFilter rf = null;
        try 
        {
            List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(srchFld1.getText(), 0));
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(srchFld2.getText(), 1));
            rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
        } 
        catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) 
        {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JtableIe ji = new JtableIe();
        ji.runGUI();
    }

    private class DateRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
    {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable myTable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(myTable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            if (!(value instanceof Date)) {
                return this;
            }
            setText(DATE_FORMAT.format((Date) value));
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

I did attempt to fix this by using this code,

`DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRendererd = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRendererd.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setCellRenderer( centerRendererd );`

However it removed the formatting on the date, which I would not like to happen.

I would appreciate any help in fixing this error and getting the Date column to center without losing any specified formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the horizontal alignment to CENTER on the DateRenderer instance?

Comment: JtableIe.java:347: error: non-static method setHorizontalAlignment(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
                                DateRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( CENTER );

Comment: Am I adding it wrong @copeg

Comment: You must call the method on an instance of the class. Or do so in the constructor. Edit: see my answer below.

Comment: I did just before  myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

Comment: Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your question. Your question is about a renderer. You only need a single row of data. The table sorter is not required. The text fields and DocumentListener have nothing to do with the problem.There is too much unrelated code to see what the problem might be. Simplify the code when learning a new concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set the horizontal alignment on the DateRenderer you use for the date column. For instance, in the setRenderers method:

```
DateRenderer dr = new DateRenderer();
dr.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
        table.setValueAt("Center", 0, 0);

        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SSCCE() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I posted this more as an example of what a `SSCCE` should be.